# How can I group by the difference of a column between rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql

I have a table of events with a `created_at` timestamp. I want to divide them into groups of events that are N seconds apart, specifically 130 seconds. Then for each group, I just need to know the lowest timestamp and the highest timestamp.

Here's some sample data (ignore the formatting of the timestamp, it's a datetime field):

```
------------------------
| id | created_at      |
------------------------
| 1  | 2013-1-20-08:00 |
| 2  | 2013-1-20-08:01 |
| 3  | 2013-1-20-08:05 |
| 4  | 2013-1-20-08:07 |
| 5  | 2013-1-20-08:09 |
| 6  | 2013-1-20-08:12 |
| 7  | 2013-1-20-08:20 |
------------------------
```

And what I would like to get as a result is:

```
-------------------------------------
| started_at      | ended_at        |
-------------------------------------
| 2013-1-20-08:00 | 2013-1-20-08:01 |
| 2013-1-20-08:05 | 2013-1-20-08:09 |
| 2013-1-20-08:12 | 2013-1-20-08:12 |
| 2013-1-20-08:20 | 2013-1-20-08:20 |
-------------------------------------
```

I've googled and searched every possible way of phrasing that question and experimented for some time, but I can't figure it out. I can already do this in Ruby, I'm just trying to figure out if it's possible to move this to the database level. If you're curious or it's easier to visualize, here's what it looks like in Ruby:

```
groups = SortedSet[*events].divide { |a,b| (a.created_at - b.created_at).abs <= 130 }
groups.map do |group|
  { started_at: group.to_a.first.created_at, ended_at: group.to_a.last.created_at }
end
```

Does anyone know how to do this in SQL, specifically PostgreSQL?

Comment: A schema as `CREATE TABLE` statement(s), plus `INSERT`s of sample data and an outline of the results you want would be very helpful. Usually what you do in things like this is get the epoch seconds, divide by the interval, and group by the result.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?  I'm not familiar with the Ruby syntax.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I've edited the question to include sample data and an expected result. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to start each new grouping when the difference from the previous is greater than 130 seconds.  You can do this with lag and date arithmetic to determine where a grouping starts.  Then do a cumulative sum to get the grouping:

```
select Grouping, min(created_at), max(created_at)
from (select t.*, sum(GroupStartFlag) over (order by created_at) as Grouping
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(created_at) over (order by created_at) as prevca,
                   (case when extract(epoch from created_at - lag(created_at) over (order by created_at)) < 130
                         then 0 else 1
                    end) as GroupStartFlag
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by Grouping;
```

The final step is the aggregate by the "grouping" identifier to get the earliest and latest dates.

Comment: Wow, I've never even heard of half those functions. Hmm, it didn't quite work. I only got back two rows, which is definitely not right.

Comment: @BrandonWeiss . . . I think I had the definition of the flag backwards.

Comment: I don't think that's it, I get the same result, just in reverse order.

Comment: @BrandonWeiss . . and my cumulative sum did `partition` rather than `order by`.  It is late where I am.

Comment: It worked! I take my hat off to you—I pulled my hair out on this one for a while. If you don't me asking, @CraigRinger mentioned using extract epoch, interval, and division. Those were the tools I assumed were right as well, but I couldn't wrap my mind around how to use them to get the result I wanted. Is there a simpler solution involving those, or is this the only way?

Comment: @BrandonWeiss . . . That solution would work if you had fixed time intervals -- for instance, if you were trying to summarize the data by hour.  In this case, you are using the data itself to define the breaks, so either a self-join or function like `lag()` is needed.